# Can front end code cause an application error in a CMS user interface?

Tags: cms, ruby-on-rails, error

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate place for this question, but here it goes.

I'm using a Ruby based CMS (which shall remain nameless) which has been throwing an application error when I try to update a piece of my site. Tech support seems to think that my front end: jQuery, CSS, HTML may be the cause. Is this even possible?

Comment: Sounds like lazy tech support

Comment: @bybe Thats what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

If the jquery / custom js is implemented within a component that is shared by both the editing and view modal states then yes, it could potentially interfere with other components.

It would be best to isolate function to form - insofar as to streamline components only necessary for "published" display vs "edit mode"

Without knowing more specifics and an example, this is the best answer I can provide. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, for the response. I tested by removing my js and still had the same application error. I just didn't think front end code would be able to affect the basic function of a CMS.

Comment: Well most CMS use a wysiwyg widget and invariably there is JS that comes with that. Jquery may or may not have been interfering - it sounds like you were able to isolate the issue insofar as to determine it was not JS that was responsible for the error....

Comment: I think its time for a new CMS, have to convince the boss...